# Property of elementary class of structures

Tags: logic

**The problem**

*Let $L$ be a language. A class $M$ of $L$-structures is called elementary if there is an $L$-theory $T$ such that $M$ is precisely the class of all models of $T$. Suppose that for such a class $M$ we have that both $M$ and its complement are elementary. Prove that there is an $L$-sentence $\phi$ such that $M$ is precisely the class of al $L$-structures that satisfy $\phi$.*

I have no idea how to approach this. I've tried using the compactness theorem so far, but it doesn't get me anywhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say $M$ is the class of all models  of $T$ and the complement $M^c$ is the class of all models of $S$. Any model of $T\cup S$ lies in $M\cap M^c$.

So some finite subset of $T\cup S$ is inconsistent. Say $\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\in T$ and $\{\phi_1,\dots,\phi_n\}\cup S$ is inconsistent. Let $\phi=\phi_1\land\dots\land\phi_n$.

Any structure in $M$ is a model of $\phi$. And any struucture not in $M$ is a model of $S$, hence is *not* a model of $\phi$, since $\{\phi\}\cup S$ is inconsistent.